# pull data from wordpress database

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query, database, mysql, conditional-content

In WordPress, i am using a plugin named "Business directory"
that plugin created a table, name "wp_wpbdp_listing_fees". and there have some column.

column name "listing_id" has all "custom post type" post id and column name "fee_id" has two different values [2 and 4]
The problem is, i want to show all post title what matched with "fee_id" = 4

custom_post_type name = wpbdp_listing

I hope this image will make it more clear :)

http://i.prntscr.com/5dd8278613d94e22bde350aa247d9d91.png

Waiting for an effective solution :)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
global $wpdb ;

// get the post_ids from the custom table
$sql = "SELECT listing_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}wpdbdp_listing_fees WHERE fee_id = %d" ;
$sql = $wpdb->prepare ($sql, 4) ;
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_col ($sql) ;

// get the custom posts from the posts table
$args = array (
    'post__in' => $post_ids,
    'post_type' => 'wpbdp_listing',
    ) ;
$posts = new WP_Query ($args) ;

foreach ($posts->posts as $the_post)
    echo $the_post->post_title ;
    }
```

Note the use of `$wpdb->prefix` in the SQL statement.

Comment: Is there any way to echo isting_id beside post title?

Comment: sure: since the `listing_id` is the post ID, just `echo $the_post->ID`